# How secure is pgAdmin to save database password?

Tags: password-management, postgresql

When we are creating a new connection with pgAdmin, we are presented with an option to save the password into our computer, so we won't have to retype it every time we want to connect with the database.

I can't find in any document how this password is stored. Is it encrypted? Saved under Windows protection? Plain text?

Does anyone knows the security implications of saving a database password in pgAdmin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pgAdmin maintainers adopted a suggestion of mine and now the stored passwords have a master password to encrypt them.

Answer (score 7):

In [pgAdmin 4.x](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/4.x/server_dialog.html) the password file location can be specified in GUI whereas [pgAdmin III](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin3/1.22/connect.html) has a fixed path. Both documentations refers to the PostgreSQL libpq (C Library) documentation for [The Password File](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html):

> The file .`pgpass` in a user's home directory can contain passwords to
>   be used if the connection requires a password (and no password has
>   been specified otherwise). On Microsoft Windows the file is named
>   `%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf`. Alternatively, a
>   password file can be specified using the connection parameter `passfile`
>   or the environment variable `PGPASSFILE`.
>
> This file should contain lines of the following format:
>
> ```
> hostname:port:database:username:password
> ```

TL;DR: It's unencrypted in a file.

Comment: In general, if a program can read it, then anything with the same privileges can read it, even if it's encrypted. For example [AACS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/AACS_encryption_key_controversy) was based on false assumption that an encryption key could stay secret while it has to be used on every device.

Comment: Well, I am no expert on it, but I think windows and other OS have mechanisms to store secrets for programs. So only that program (and admin accounts) will have access to those secrets. So I was kinda counting on it

Comment: I think it's in a DB for PgAdmin 4: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/193093/16892